# JavaScript: удаление класса с задержкой

Tags: javascript

При скролле страницы, блоку добавляется css класс, при скролле обратно класс удаляется:

```
else {
            wrapperContainer.classList.remove('fixed-container');
        }
```

Класс удаляется резко, как сделать задержку в 0.5сек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызов функции произойдет спустя 0,5сек

```
else {
  setTimeout(function(){
    wrapperContainer.classList.remove('fixed-container');
  }, 500);
}
```